# Macro including loop as an expression?

Tags: c++, c, macros

I use a lot of macros which implement common loop operations. For example:

```
#define findIdx(count, cond, out) out = count; for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)  \
                                                  if (cond) out= i;
```

used like:

```
int arr[5] = {1, 12, 13, 19, 21};
int idx;
findIdx(5, arr[i] == 13, idx); //idx is set to 2
```

Is there a clever way to implement this functionality as an expression, without sacrificing convenience, and without using c++11 (not available to me)? So that I could assign the result to a variable directly, or use the result as a parameter to a function?

Comment: You can replace this with `idx = std::find(arr, arr + size, 13) - arr;` Wrap this in a templated function if you like.

Comment: Any reason you have to stick to using a macro instead of using an inline function?

Comment: @NeilKirk The idea is that cond is an arbitrary condition, not simply testing for a particular value.

Comment: @Vigabrand Then you can use `std::find_if` although it's not as convienient without C++11

Comment: @NeilKirk Exactly, its not worth it for me without c++11

Answer (score 0):

To embed a statement in an expression:

- You can use a [GCC statement expression](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html)
- You can use a [Clang Block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocks_%28C_language_extension%29)
- In C++03, you can take a static member of an anonymous struct in an expression (or at least g++ doesn't complain):

  ```
  foo(
      ((struct { static void f() { return; } }){}).f
  );
  ```

  (so the macro would put the loop code in the body of `f`)

There is no way to do this in standard-compliant C, any version (short of Greenspunning). The standard explicitly disallows using `setjmp` in comma-expressions, which is otherwise the first thing you'd probably consider.

Comment: I don't think this makes things better.

Comment: Interesting. Unfortunately, the c++03 suggestion doesn't work in VS2008.